# Numerical method to solve difference equation

Tags: numerical-methods, recurrence-relations, computer-science, floating-point

I am solving the following problem:

Write a program to generate the first 60 terms in the sequence given by the difference equation: $$x_{k+1}=2.25x_{k}-0.5x_{k-1}$$
with starting values $x_1=\frac{1}{3}, x_2=\frac{1}{12}$. The exact solution is given by $x_k=\frac{4^{1-k}}{3}$. Make a semilog plot of the values you obtain as a function of k.

**My attemp:**

My program (in Octave) is the following:

```
function x=diff
 n=60;
 x(1)=1/3;
 x(2)=1/12;
  for i=3:n
    x(i)=2.25*x(i-1)-0.5*x(i-2);
  endfor
   k=1:60;
 semilogy(k,x)
endfunction
```

I performed the operations with the solution that they give me in the problem and I obtained the following graph:
[image]

But I don't know where the problem is, in my opinion my code is correct. I tried to see if the solution was not correct, but the general solution for the difference equation is the following: $x_k=c_1 4^{-k}+c_2 2^k$, and with the initial values it agrees with the one given in the exercise.

Beforehand thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like you're encountering round off error since the analytic solution goes like $4^{-k}$, so you've done everything right

Comment: Only that? Is it just the fault of the rounding error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution is
$$
x_k=A·4^{-k}+B·2^k.
$$
As the coefficient $A=\frac43$ of the exact solution is not representable in binary floating point, the numerical sequence will behave as if $B$ was some small value around $10^{-15}$. The first and second term become about equal at $k=17$, for the following sequence elements the second term will dominate, leading rapidly away from the exact solution.